# xcode 7 buttons overlapping

Tags: xcode, constraints, xcode7

I am new to Xcode, I am trying to make a few selections that should sit in descending order such as:

option1
option2
option3
option4

but when placing the constraints in Xcode 7 of: Equal widths, Center vertically in container, and center horizontally in container I get all the buttons and even the label over lapping in the simulator any one know how I can get them centered on the simulator?

I am using Xcode 7.

Comment: can you show screen shot of the interface builder and the result?

Comment: They will overlap if you set all of them as centered vertically.  Try just centering `option3` vertically and use vertical offsets for the others.

Comment: I dont have enough reputation to add pictures unfortunately

Comment: how do I use vertical offsets? sorry I am very new with xcode

Comment: I am in the stackview and I dragged the buttons but upon building they are aligned to the left of the screen on the simulator

Comment: Let's forget the stack view for now.  It's new and I haven't used it enough to effectively explain it.  I added an answer to explain how to set the vertical offsets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your buttons will overlap if you set all of them as centered vertically. Try:

1. Center *Option3* both horizontally and vertically in the view.
2. Center *Option1*, *Option2*, and *Option4* horizontally in the view.
3. Add a vertical offset from *Option3* to *Option2*.  To do this <kbd>Control</kbd>-drag from *Option3* to *Option2* and select *Vertical Spacing* from the pop up.
4. Add a vertical offset from *Option2* to *Option1* in the same way.
5. Add a vertical offset from *Option3* to *Option4* in the same way.

Comment: Thank you so much do I just add a vertical off set to the label above option 1 to get it centered as well?